# Which iteration is faster in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, loops, foreach, iteration

I am working on a project that i have to iterate through an array with a large amount of elements. I would like to know which iteration method is faster (if there is actually any significant difference).

classic way:

```
for ( var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    sum += arr[ i ];
}
```

each way:

```
$.each( arr, function( index, value ) {
    sum += value;
});
```

or this way:

```
for (var item in obj) {
    sum += obj[ item ];
}
```

Comment: try http://jsperf.com/ !!!

Comment: http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-jquery-each-vs-for-loop

Comment: @ArunPJohny - why not make yours an answer as measurement IS the way to answer a question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of performance metrics, as I am too lazy to do so and others have provided good links, I'll just use supporting empirical evidence.

**Standard For Loop**

**A simple for loop like your first example will be the most efficient looping construct**. The only operation being performed within the loop is `sum += arr[i]` which with no additional overhead in allocating memory, invoking functions, or other operations etc...

**jQuery.each**

The jquery `$.each` while convient, is going to be slower simply because you incur the overhead of anonymous function you defined as will as the need to invoke it once per iteration (in addition to any other operations jquery performs under the hood).

**For In Syntax**

The last will have the worst performance because what you are doing is looping through all of the indices of the array, which according to a number of benchmarks I've seen is severely slower. As to the reason why, you would need to ask that on a browser/version case by case basis with their devs. :) Unless someone else has insight on the issue? What we can assume safely is the using this approach incurs the following operations in your example:

1. Obtaining the index
2. Obtaining the value for the array at said index
3. Accumulating the sum with said value

So logically, we can deduce that the `for in` syntax would take **at least three times** as many operations to perform the same sum as a standard for loop.

Comment: You want to answer a performance question WITHOUT measuring anything?  That is NEVER a good idea.

Comment: And here the link that demonstrates the performance difference.
http://jsfiddle.net/5pr4w/

Comment: I answered a performance question with empirical evidence, which is already backed by data (let's call it a poor man's source citing). I see no need to steam head into retesting the wheel that plenty of others have already. The data is already there. Why in the world would I do it over again? That mindset, IMO, is NEVER a good idea. :)

Comment: I don't see any measured data in your answer.  You're trying to deduce an answer based on reasoning.  Sometimes that works, but sometimes you get very surprised at what a browser optimizes for.

Comment: typo good sir. as stated at the beginning of my answer `... supporting empirical evidence`.

Comment: I looked up the definition of empirical and it says "verified by observation or experience, rather than theory or logic".

Comment: I'll redact and say that I used a mixture of both then. My mistake in choice of words. But nonetheless, it still is true. Theoretically and logically my answer is well founded, empirically I have seen this outcome many times through trail and observation when writing code, and the data others have collected supports my findings.

Answer (score 1):

As you are looking for an measurement in terms of performance, the best way is to test the different scenarios to create a benchmark and run it against multiple browsers to see how it performs.

In javascript(client), [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) is a good tool to do this.

As per [this test](http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-jquery-each-vs-for-loop), the simple for loop seems to performing better that other varients.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, You can go with **foreach** loop.

But **for** loop is fater, since it is javascript.

Comment: There is no `foreach` loop in jQuery.  There is a `forEach()` method on an array in modern browsers.

Comment: And jQuery *is* JavaScript. So that's not the reason.